# Implementing an Amazon Lex chatbot in a Node.js app

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created a simple Node.js app that displays an iterface for a chabot, the bot is published and the following code is my lex.js file on the routes folder of my app. I deployed the app on AWS Beanstalk to test it but whenever I input a message I get a POST error, what a I missing o should change for it to work properly?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const { DynamoDBClient } = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb");
const { LexRuntimeServiceClient } = require("@aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-service");

const dynamoClient = new DynamoDBClient({ region: "us-east-1" });
const lexClient = new LexRuntimeServiceClient({ region: "us-east-1" });

router.post('/', async function (req, res) {
  try {
    // Log the request body to the console
    console.log(req.body);

    // Send user's input to Amazon Lex
    const lexResponse = await lexClient.postContent({
      botName: 'Contactos',
      contentType: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
      inputStream: Buffer.from(req.body.message),
      userId: req.session.id
    });
    
    const responseText = lexResponse.message;

    // Send response back to the client
    res.send({ resp: responseText });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send('Error');
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Deploy a Node.js app with Amazon Lex implementation, but can't reach the chatbot

Comment: Hi - please provide more information around the error itself. Perhaps share the stacktrace.

To add: I notice you don't have a version or alias in your `postContent` call. That's typically a mandatory field when calling Lex.